# Laravel blade + vue render ajax data couple?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-blade

i want to write ajax rendering news using blade + vue.

```
<div id="news">
    <div class="l_news">
        <div class="post" v-for="post in posts">
            <div class="image" style="background: url({{ asset('images/car.jpg') }}) no-repeat center / cover">
                <div class="title">@{{ post.title }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">@{{ post.desc }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some problem with rendering post image.

But i can't use

`url({{ asset('@{{ post.image }}') }})`

How to write correctly?

Now i'm using :style="".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a php function inside v-for because it's out of your context.

But maybe you can do the following:

```
:style="'background: url({{url('/images')}}" + '/' + post.image"
```

And simply append the name of the image to your url.